# How to use the correct regex

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to get the value for each '/' but I can't get the correct output because of the special characters included in the file. How can I use the correct regex to be used in the checking? I am using the `<xsl:analyze-string>` element to get the value. Here is my sample file:

**INPUTFile:**

```
<Communication>
   <DialNumber>Phone/+31-3424-27385/null/Phone/+06-32-7890-565/Mobile(Office)/null/+313-(424)-28500/Fax</DialNumber>
</Communication>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
<Communication>
   <ChannelCode>Phone</ChannelCode>
   <UseCode>null</UseCode>
   <DialNumber>+31-3424-27385</DialNumber>
</Communication>
<Communication>
   <ChannelCode>Phone</ChannelCode>
   <UseCode>Mobile(Office)</UseCode>
   <DialNumber>+06-32-7890-565</DialNumber>
</Communication>
<Communication>
   <ChannelCode>null</ChannelCode>
   <UseCode>Fax</UseCode>
   <DialNumber>+313-(424)-28500</DialNumber>
</Communication>
```

**XSLTCode**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="DialNumber">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="normalize-space()" regex="(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <Communication>
                    <ChannelCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
                    </ChannelCode>
                    <UseCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(3)"/>
                    </UseCode>
                <DialNumber>
                    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
                </DialNumber>
            </Communication>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need to check the 1st 3 words after '/' and the next 3 words again, and the last 3 words. It looks like this:

`Phone/+31-3424-27385/null`

`Phone/+06-32-7890-565/Mobile(Office)`

`null/+313-(424)-28500/Fax`

The 1st regex I need to assign in `<Channel>`, 2nd in `<DialNumber>` and 3rd in `<UseCode>`.

Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If - as it seems - your input is organized in groups of three, you could do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="Communication">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="tokenize(DialNumber, '/')" group-by="(position()-1) idiv 3">
        <Communication>
            <ChannelCode>
                <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]" />
            </ChannelCode>
            <UseCode>
                <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[3]" />
            </UseCode>
            <DialNumber>
                <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[2]" />
            </DialNumber>
        </Communication>        
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/3MvmrA5/1

Answer (score 1):

No need for `analyze-string` here, `tokenize()` will work fine

```
<xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize(., '/')"/>
<xsl:for-each-group select="$tokens" group-adjacent="(position()-1) idiv 3">
        <Communication>
            <ChannelCode>
                <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]" />
            </ChannelCode>
            <UseCode>
                <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[3]" />
            </UseCode>
            <DialNumber>
                <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[2]" />
            </DialNumber>
        </Communication>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: And the important difference is ... ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your answer. Don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your `analyze-string` with the following if the separator is `/` character:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="normalize-space()" regex="(.+?)/(.+?)/(.+?)(/|$)" >
```

Here, `(.+?)/` does a lazy search matching a set of characters before a `/`. And `/|$` will consider the last token after slash, as `$` denotes end of string.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.