# XSLT group every nth item in to new group

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have done few XSLT in the past, but I am facing challenge in this.
I am working with PLC tag, for each tag i am getting three rowset node, so after every three Rowset i need to create new "Row" group.
Updated with XSLT

Input XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Rowsets >
    <Rowset>
        <Row>
            <DateTime>2021-07-05T07:33:38</DateTime>
            <WC_ID>0001</WC_ID>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
    <Rowset>
        <Row>
            <DateTime>2021-07-05T07:33:38</DateTime>
            <Tag1_Good>6817</Tag1_Good>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
    <Rowset>
        <Row>
            <DateTime>2021-07-05T07:33:38</DateTime>
            <Tag1_Bad>0</Tag1_Bad>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
    <Rowset>
        <Row>
            <DateTime>2021-07-05T07:33:38</DateTime>
            <WC_ID>0002</WC_ID>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
    <Rowset>
        <Row>
            <DateTime>2021-07-05T07:33:38</DateTime>
            <Tag2_Good>6800</Tag2_Good>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
    <Rowset>
        <Row>
            <DateTime>2021-07-05T07:33:38</DateTime>
            <Tag2_Bad>0</Tag2_Bad>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

**Expected output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Rowset>
        <Row>
           
            <WC_ID>0001</WC_ID>
            <Tag1_Good>6817</Tag1_Good>
            <Tag1_Bad>0</Tag1_Bad>
        </Row>
        <Row>
           
            <WC_ID>0002</WC_ID>
            <Tag1_Good>6800</Tag1_Good>
            <Tag1_Bad>0</Tag1_Bad>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
```

My XSLT:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <Rowsets >  
            <xsl:variable name="batchSize" select="3"/>
                <Rowset>           
                    <xsl:for-each select="/Rowsets/Rowset[position() mod $batchSize >= 0]"               
                        <Row>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Row/*[2]" />
                        </Row>
                    </xsl:for-each>              
                </Rowset>
            </Rowsets>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am not able to make this into a new group

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/45160347/3016153. Unfortunately, SO won't let me close this as duplicate because the answer there is not upvoted or accepted. In any case, this should be closed because it is not a question but a request for code-writing service.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use the correct regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45155494/how-to-use-the-correct-regex)

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
<Rowsets>
      <xsl:variable name="batchSize" select="3"/>
      <Rowset>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Rowsets/Rowset">
          <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
          <xsl:if test="$pos mod $batchSize = 0">
            <Row>
              <WC_ID>
                <xsl:value-of select="/Rowsets/Rowset[$pos - 2]/Row/*[2]"/>
              </WC_ID>
              <Tag1_Good>
                <xsl:value-of select="/Rowsets/Rowset[$pos - 1]/Row/*[2]"/>
              </Tag1_Good>
              <Tag1_Bad>
                <xsl:value-of select="/Rowsets/Rowset[$pos]/Row/*[2]"/>
              </Tag1_Bad>
            </Row>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Rowset>
    </Rowsets>
```